# Pic programming: what is the variable type of a port bit in MikroC?

Tags: variables, pic, mikroc

I'm programming in C in the MikroC IDE for a pic16f887 and I want more versatility with pins such as being able to put them into an array, passing them as arguments to functions...etc.

So I was wondering what the "type" of a pin such as `PORTB.F1` is? 
How would I store bits into an array?

Would this work?

```
const char pinArr[3] = {PORTB.F1, PORTC.F1, PORTD.F1};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this with a set of inputs pins. A digital input pin should be read as an int, specifically it will be 0 or 1. Your `char` array probably wouldn't work as a pin with an input of 0 would be read as a NULL character, which would signal the end of the string to anything expecting a normal c string. However there should be nothing stopping you using an `int` array.

Comment: If Shubham uses the "char" type just as "enough space for 8 bytes" then the meaning of a NULL will not matter (as long he does not use printf or similar functions on the array). I find it cleaner to define a proper type similar to this "typedef unsigned char UInt8".

Answer (score 0):

You can define your pins and use the predefined names instead. It's a lot more easier.
For example:

```
#define front_sensor                PORTE.F0
#define left_sensor                 PORTE.F1
#define right_sensor                PORTE.F2
```

or

```
unsigned char sensor = PORTE.F0;
```